# Storing certain input

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6, python-idle

Here's my code;

```
locat_file = 'info/locat.txt'

Import os

If not os.path.exists(locat_file):
   #Ask location
   locat = raw_input("Where are you from?\n").title
   with open(locat_file, "w") as f:
         f.write(locat)
         f.close
```

This code works great. I use the same code for storing names. Only problem is if you say 'i live in Ireland' or 'my name is bob' it will save your name as 'my name is bob' when I only want to save the bob part?

Comment: If I input "You can call me Jon if you like", how do you figure out which part is the name?

Comment: Unless you had a list of acceptable names or had complex text processing you can't. Both of those solutions are stupid, a simpler solution would be the answer I posted.
If the person is from a non-English speaking region, they might have names "S'Fiso" or "Gerhad", so keeping a list of English names would be really silly. I have seen these kind of limitations programmed often, which means you often see "The name you entered is not valid" messages in my part of the world

Comment: @Morgoth my point exactly. Names are very difficult, see e.g. http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Alternatively, just tell the user to only input their name and nothing else, then whatever they give you is their name. Don't ask such ambiguous questions otherwise they will be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there is a space in the answer, although there are many more complex checks you could do:

```
If not os.path.exists(locat_file):
   #Ask location
   while True: # keep asking question until you get an acceptable answer
       locat = raw_input("Where are you from?\n").title #Synchronous function, will wait for return before code continues to be interpreted
       if ' ' not in locat: # condition(s) the answer need to meet
           break
       else:
           print("there are no spaces allowed in a name")
   with open(locat_file, "w") as f:
         f.write(locat)
         f.close
```

*Alternatively, just tell the user to only input their name and nothing else, then whatever they give you is their name*